# How to add a list-item at specific position

Tags: jquery, append, listitem

I'd like to add a `<li>` at a specific position, for example:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Position 1</li>
    <li>Position 2</li>
    <li>Position 4</li>
<ul>
```

Let's say that I want to add a new `<li>` below/after `<li>Position 2</li>`, how can I do it using jQuery?

I've tried to do it using the code below:

```
$('#list li:eq(1)').append('<li>Position 3</li>');
```

But, it didn't work, because it appends the `<li>` inside the `<li>Position 2</li>`, instead add the `<li>` below/after the `<li>Position 2</li>`.

Can someone give me some help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 85):

You have to use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `append()`:

> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#list li:eq(1)').after('<li>Position 3</li>');
```

---

The documentation of `append()` clearly says:

> Insert content (...) **to the end** of each element.

---

For completeness:

Note that `:eq(n)` matches the `n`th element of the matching element set, whereas [`:nth-child(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) matches the `n`th child of the parent.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `after()` or `insertAfter()`
http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('<option val="position3">Position3</option>').insertAfter('#list :nth-child(<give childnumber here>)')
```

index start with 1

Answer (score 2):

Check `insertAfter` [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)