# Is there a quick and easy way of using jQuery to insert an <li> into the middle of an <ol>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I can use append() to add an 'li' to the end of a list, but how would I add it to a specific index? Would I just have to manipulate an array and then refresh the list with the updated array? Or is there already a function written in jQuery that allows me to do this?

I have tried looking in the jQuery API Documentation, but I just started with JavaScript earlier this week and I am having trouble understanding everything.

Comment: This is what I am currently using to append the 'li' to the 'ol': $('.todos').append(todoLi);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2932205/4028085 use `after()` instead of `append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a function to add an element after or before a node ([`.before()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/)/[`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/)).

You can then use `.eq()` to select an element and place your element where you want.

Here a little function that do what you want (0 based index). It is important to check if the index element exist, else it will never be put in the DOM:

```
function appendAt($what, $to, index){
    var $target = $to.children().eq(Math.max(0, index));
    if($target.length !== 0){
        $target.before($what);
    }else{
        $what.appendTo($to);
    }
}

//Use it like that
appendAt($('<li>'), $('.todos'), 5); //The li with become the 6th element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `nth-child()` and `after`

```
$( ".todos li:nth-child(2)" ).after(todoLi);
```

If you want to insert todoLi after the 2nd item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet to show you how .after() works.

```js
$('ul li:eq(1)').after("<li>hello world</li>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this, where index is whatever spot you'd like to insert at.

```
var index = 3;
$('ul li:nth-of-type('+index+')').after('<li><a href="/link">Zac was here</a></li>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ol li').eq(index).after(your_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out which element is in the middle and `insertAfter` it.

```
var newLi = $('<li></li')
var halfway = Math.floor($('ol > li').length);
newLi.insertAfter($('ol > li')[halfway]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the jQuery .after() method utilizing the :nth-child() selector. For example, if you wanted to try adding your li after the 2nd li and before the 3rd

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).after('<li>added!</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="list">
    <li><a href="#">list 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">list 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Tag</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list 4</a></li>
</ol>

$('li.active').after('<li><a href="#">New Tag</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be

```
var newLi="<li>This is test</li>";
$(".list li:nth-child(2)").after(newLi);
```

Remember the child index starts from 1, so 2 here means after the second li